# Connecting to C# socket through public IP address

Tags: c#, sockets, ip, ip-address

Good evening everyone, 
I'm having trouble connecting to a Socket using my IP address. I can connect by using my local address, but no luck getting it to work with my public one.
If I go on www.canyouseeme.org I can see that my server receives the connection and the site says it can see the service.
Here is the code. Client

```
public void Connect() {
    IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse("xx.xx.143.138");
    clientSocket = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    // Connect
    clientSocket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 7777));
}
```

Server:

```
private void Listen() {
    IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Any;
    serverSocket = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 7777));
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Emiliano

Comment: On your router, you may need to forward the port to your pc.

Comment: Yeah, and the windows level firewall - it doesn ot magically open a port.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but then port is forwarded and the firewall is disabled. As I said the port is seen as open from canyouseeme.org

Comment: You need to have a route between the two PCs.  So first you must verify that PING IP works.  So use cmd.exe >PING IP.  It is possible you have a route in one direction but not reverse direction .  For a connection to work you need both forward route and reverse route.  So try sending from server and see if client gets message.  I suspect there is something wrong with the IP/Mask on the Server.

Comment: I am able to ping the server from the client machine, checking the reverse now

Comment: Yes, you are right, I can't ping the client from the server. I'll try to fix that and get back to you. Thanks :)

Comment: Got it fixed. Thanks everybody :)